# User profile in Session variable

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, simplemembership

I've a pretty basic question related to user profile storage along a session.

Let's say that I've an Account table that stores user profiles and that I've linked this table to ASP.NET SimpleMembership. Once a user is logged in, controllers may need to retrieve information in or based from her Account. What I'm doing right now is querying the database each time I need data, with something similar to this: `_dbContext.Accounts.Where(a => a.EmailAddress == User.Identity.Name).Single()`.

But I'm afraid that this may cause unnecessary load on the DB and think that a better idea (perhaps it's what everybody does!) is to store the Account object in a Session variable once a user logs in, enabling direct access without re-querying the DB.
Is this the usual way to do it? Isn't there a risk of "de-sync" between the Session variable and the authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Our website uses this same type of method for a user-type object at login. Upon confirmed login we store the user object in a session variable. If something is changed or updated the object is updated and depending on the circumstance the change is updated in the database as well (timing meaning update immediately following the change or, after gathering a group of changes).

It just depends on how complex your system is. Ours is fairly complex, and this has proved to be a pretty solid way - without requiring constant maintenence and updates.